# Laravel : Удалить строки по двум параметрам

Tags: eloquent, laravel5

Всем привет,

В модели app/UserChatNewMessage.php :
Определены ссылки на другие модели:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'user_chat_message_id', 'user_id' ];

public function userChatMessage(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserChatMessage', 'user_chat_message_id','id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id','id');
}
```

И соответствующие методы с hasMany...
И мне нужно удалить строки(их может быть несколько) из UserChatNewMessage по двум параметрам что-то вроде :

```
public static function clear( int $user_chat_message_id, int $user_id )
{
    $userChatNewMessageList = with(new UserChatNewMessage)->userChatMessage($user_chat_message_id)->user($user_id)->get();
    foreach( $userChatNewMessageList as $nextUserChatNewMessage ) {
        $nextUserChatNewMessage->delete();
    }
}
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()
```

Понятно, как сделать фильтр используя $quoteModel->where по двум условиям ...

А можно ли выполнить поиск используя методы userChatMessage(),  user() ?

Спасибо !